# Is it possible to detect duplicate image files?

Tags: python, image

I have over 10K files for products, the problem is is that many of the images are duplicates.

If there is no image, there is a standard image that says 'no image'.

How can I detect if the image is this standard 'no image' image file?

**Update**
The image is a different name, but it is exactly the same image otherwise.

People are saying Hash, so would I do this?

```
im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read())
img = im.open(im)
md5.md5(img)
```

Comment: Is it really the same image (binary) or just an image with the same name?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate"?  Same name?  Same Checksum?  Same exact bytes?

Comment: We really need more information.  In addition to the questions already posed, how are these stored?  Are these stored as directories that contain an image file along with other files? Are the stored in a database? Are they stored some other way?  What does the system look like? Do all of the "No Image" products use the same file for their image or is it a copy of the same image duplicated for each product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a script for this a while back. First it scans all files, noting their sizes in a dictionary. You endup with:

```
images[some_size] = ['x/a.jpg', 'b/f.jpg', 'n/q.jpg']
images[some_other_size] = ['q/b.jpg']
```

Then, for each key (image size) where there's more than 1 element in the dictionary, I'd read some fixed amount of the file and do a hash. Something like:

```
possible_dupes = [size for size in images if len(images[size]) > 1]
for size in possible_dupes:
    hashes = defaultdict(list)
    for fname in images[size]:
        m = md5.new()
        hashes[ m.update( file(fname,'rb').read(10000) ).digest() ] = fname
    for k in hashes:
       if len(hashes[k]) <= 1: continue
       for fname in hashes[k][1:]:
           os.remove(fname)
```

This is all off the top of my head, haven't tested the code, but you get the idea.

Comment: All Microsoft Bitmap files without RLE compression which have the same pixel dimensions will be the same size. As will XPMs with the same-length internal name, as will PNGs with no compression, as will Netpbm images... The list goes on and on. But I agree; checking the size will help to avoid meaningless collisions

Answer (score 15):

As a sidenote, for images, I find raster data hashes to be far more effective than file hashes.

ImageMagick provides reliable way to compute such hashes, and there are different bindings for python available. It helps to detect same images with different lossless compressions and different metadata.

Usage example:

```
>>> import PythonMagick
>>> img = PythonMagick.Image("image.png")
>>> img.signature()
'e11cfe58244d7cf98a79bfdc012857a9391249dca3aedfc0fde4528eed7f7ba7'
```

Comment: This method is much better than file hashes in order to compare against PNGs and BMPs, two of the same images with different EXIF data or encoding techniques should be considered similar.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. This was incredibly useful to me as some of my images had been tagged and some had not. This lets me find duplicate images regardless of their metadata.

Comment: A link to the appropriate ImageMagick documentation on this feature would be helpful. For example a google search for [ImageMagick raster data hash](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=imagemagick+raster+data+hash&oq=imagemagick+raster+data+hash&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.278029.278492.1.278631.5.5.0.0.0.3.301.1022.0j2j2j1.5.0....0...1c.1.42.psy-ab..5.2.237.In0DXDbzF3w&pbx=1&biw=1063&bih=799&cad=cbv&sei=QDVuU6K8BojPsAS81YDoDA) provides maybe or maybe not useful information to someone who doesn't necessarily know exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: @jptros I've added sample code, but keep in mind that PythonMagick is not maintained anymore. There are some other Python bindings for IM, which are better maintained, but I don't have sample code for them.

Comment: having problems installing ImageMagick with python 3.x, is still only available for 2.5?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are talking about same images in terms of same image data.

Compute the [**hash**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the "no image" image and compare it to the hashes of the other images. If the hashes are the same, it is the same file.

Comment: This would also be a good way to detect duplicates elsewhere.  Start computing hashes of the images, and then for each image, make sure it doesn't already exist.  If it does, you have a duplicate.  If not, add it to the database and move on.

Comment: Actually, if Blankman is looking for duplicates of a particular file (as opposed to finding all sets of duplicates in the collection), hashes are counter-productive — see my answer.

Comment: @Gilles: Interesting. Yeah, I know that you would have to read all the files completely, but I never said that this is the best or a fast approach ;) Gave you +1.

Comment: So how do I do this hash on an image?

Comment: @Blankman: Have a look at the hashlib module: http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble installing PythonMagick on Fedora but [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/) (another ImageMagick binding) worked.

```
from wand.image import Image

img = Image(filename="image.jpg")
print(img.signature)
```

Just be sure to install everything first:

```
yum install python3-wand ImageMagick
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for exact duplicates of a particular image: load this image into memory, then loop over your image collection; skip any file that doesn't have the same size; compare the contents of the files that have the same size, stopping at the first difference.

Computing a hash in this situation is actually counter-productive because you'd have to read each file completely into memory (instead of being able to stop at the first difference) and perform a CPU-intensive task on it.

If there are several sets of duplicates, on the other hand, computing a hash of each file is better.

If you're also looking for visual near-duplicates, [findimagedupes](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) can help you.

Comment: He can compute a hash and also save the image's size and skip the images with different sizes. It would be smart to test what takes more time. Computing hash or comparing two images byte by byte.

Comment: It may seem like a waste of effort to compute all those hashes, but comparing N files to each other is O(N*N). With sufficient number of files, the O(N) algorithm calculating hashes and comparing in a `set()` or `dict()` will be more efficient. Note that you don't need to hash the whole file - the first kb or so is likely to be just as useful as a first check

Answer (score 0):

Hash them. Collisions are duplicates (at least, it's a mathematical impossibility that they aren't the same file).

Comment: I assume you meant _"improbability"_, not "impossibility".

Comment: You should _always_ consider the possibility of hash collisions. Multiply the **cost** of a collision with the **probability of a collision** to get the **expected cost**. Usually the expected cost is small because even if the cost is a million dollars, the probability of a collision is so small. But baby photos etc. are irreplacable, so maybe some extra effort is required sometimes ;)

Comment: @gnibbler This is why we keep backups.